# add margin to image prepended with jquery .attr()

Tags: jquery, css

I am prepending an image using to a span using .attr() and want to add a top margin to the image only. But when I add css to the jquery, it moves the entire span, not just the image. I've twiddled around with this for awhile, but can't figure it out.

**How can I add CSS to the prepended image only and not to the entire span?**

Here's the code.

```
    $("<img />").prependTo('span.album:contains("Toto")').attr({
        src: '/images/toto.jpg',
        alt: '',
        height: '24',
                    style: 'margin-top:3px;' //this moves the whole span
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you change the margin of the image, it is increasing the height of the current line. Since the image and the span are `display: inline`, it will also increase the spacing above the span because they are both on the same line. Consider floating the image so that the image doesn't increase the line height.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but that still moves the entire span and not just the image.

Comment: That's a css problem, not a js problem. When you change the margin of the image, it is increasing the height of the current line. Since the image and the span are `display: inline`, it will also increase the spacing above the span because they are both on the same line. Consider floating the image.

Comment: I actually kept my original code and added a float--works fine. Thank you. Would you add your comment to your answer? I'll accept and upvote it. Just want to make it clear to googlers what the real issue is.

Comment: @chowwy you're right, prependTo still returns the image, so the order doesn't matter. Sorry for the confusion!